# Node.js express framework serve static swf file

Tags: node.js, flash, express

I need to serve static swf using express framework generating dynamic view similar to:

```
    app.get('/*', function(req, res){
// serve swf here

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't just declare a static folder?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

If you don't want to use the Express static folder, then you can just read the file off of the file system and serve it directly.

```
res.sendfile('path/to/my.swf');
```